# Sprint Burndown/Burnups in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, burndowncharts

I need a sprint burndown chart on our dashboard in Azure Devops, but none of the available seem to fit my needs.
The burndown should reflect number of tasks, bugs and User Stories in the sprint, but the ones described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-sprint-burndown?view=azure-devops) do not fulfill those needs. They either require hour estimates on each task/bug, or can give a count of one of the above Item types (Task, Bug or User Story) at a time. The "Sprint Burndown (Legacy) widget" is what comes closest to my needs, only that it does not show the burndown from Sprint start, and does not have an ideal trend line, which I would also like.
Moreover, a burnup chart would also be nice to have, but again nothing satisfies that.

Comment: The article [Add a dashboard widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=azure-devops) describe how you can develop a custom widget.

Comment: @Jihad Haddad Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 2):

The widgets provided in the dashboard are all designed. As the document stated: You can define remaining work based on Stories **or** Tasks, and by counting the work items or summing a field. So if you want to react to the count of tasks, bugs and stories in a Sprint Burn down widget, it is currently not possible. You could submit a feature request in our [Develop Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) site to promote development of richer features.

With the [burndown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets?view=azure-devops#choose-the-teams-and-work-items-to-chart) widget, you can display the number of stories and bugs together. Because this widget has `Include bugs on the Stories backlog` option. If you select the Stories backlog you are presented with this additional option. Place a checkmark in the box to include bugs along with user stories in your burndown. But this also can't display the count of tasks together.

[image]

If you want to reflect the number of these items , you can choose to add a few more widgets. Or as Mar Tin said in the comment, you can develop a custom widget.

**Update**:

With queries you can list the work items of interest (items in the Requirements category or estimated, remaining, and completed work for items in the Task category), and then define a chart that shows either a count of work items or a sum of a numeric field.

[image]

Then create a chart based on this query and add to dashboard.

[image]

For details,please refer to documents: [Remaining and completed work queries and charts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-numeric?view=azure-devops#remaining-and-completed-work-queries-and-charts); [Create work tracking charts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/charts?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for confirming that it is not me who does not know how to. However, is there any reason for not making it possible to include all the types I mentioned above? Actually we also have custom types which I also want to include. Is there a widget freeware database I can download from, where some has implemented this? If not, then maybe I should develop one.

Comment: I updated another method in the answer, you can create a chart based on the query and then add it to the dashboard.